# Avoid line breaks after \lstinline

Tags: listings, line-breaking, inline

I'm writing a computer science paper with LaTeX and have a lot of inline code.
Now, when this code is followed by a comma and is at the end of line, the line break is inserted *before* the comma, which is wrong and looks weird.

Here's an example:

> This is normal text with some `inlined code`, `more inlined code`
>   , and `even more inlined code`.

Basically, the corresponding LaTeX code is (although I'm having problems reproducing the issue in this MWE):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
This is normal text with some \lstinline{inlined code}, 
\lstinline{more inlined code}, and \lstinline{even more inlined code}.
\end{document}
```

How can I avoid the line break between the code and the comma?
I found that putting `\mbox` around the comma and `\lstinline` macro works, but this feels not right.
Are there better solutions?

If the problem is due to settings in my universities `.sty` or `.cls` files, is there a way I could quickly find the offending option? … That is, without commenting most of it and then re-introduce every option one by one.

---

**edit**

Finally managed to whip up a short working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}
Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ball tip shankle i Nrtdy uses \lstinline{System.LongerCode}, whereas Uiae uses \lstinline{System.OtherCode}.
\end{document}
```

Removing `breaklines=true` seems like to avoid the problem. This in unfortunate, since I need automatic line breaks in listings in other places.
Is there a sensible fix?

Comment: Can you cook up a small example such that people can demonstrate solutions on that example that would suit your needs?

Comment: @percusse: It's difficult to get the line breaks at the correct spot. There's the thesis template I have to use, and I'm having problems getting the line break to show up in an MWE :( So maybe it is some weird setting in the template …

Comment: If I typeset your example with a narrow measure, the comma is never detached from the `\lstinline` code. I'm afraid it depends on the `.cls` or `.sty` files you're using.

Comment: @egreg: Is there a simple way to find out what part of the cls/sty files is causing this?

Comment: Look for something containing `\lst`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the option `breakatwhitespace`:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breaklines,
  breakatwhitespace,
}
```

Since text typeset in `\ttfamily` won't be hyphenated, this will do as you want and it should have no other consequence.

Comment: I often have long identifiers (without whitespace, but with periods), that need breaking, e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`

Comment: It's possible to use `\lstset` inside curly braces and set a property only inside it. Using `{\lstset{breakatwhitespace} ... paragraph with text and code ...}` works without messing up the rest of the document. Thanks!

Comment: I found with this solution, that longer variable names without spaces (for me underscores), would push out into the right margin. For example, use `\lstinline{System.LongerCode.LongerStill}` in the minimal example in the question.